# How to resize a graphic?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, resize

I have two pictureBoxes "source" and "dest". Now I would like to resize the "source" image and display it in my "dest"-picturebox.

**Question:**
How can I resize my "source" image and display it in my "dest"-picturebox?

Here is my code which only display the same image again:

```
private void pictureBoxZoom_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = new Settings();


        // Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
        Graphics Draw = e.Graphics;
        Draw.ScaleTransform(2, 2);       // rescale by factor 2

        IntPtr hDC = Draw.GetHdc(); // Get a handle to pictureBoxZoom.

        Draw.ReleaseHdc(hDC); // Release pictureBoxZoom handle.
    }
```

Comment: Does the picture need to be resized or would it be sufficient to have it displayed properly? In that case, the [PictureBox.SizeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx)-Property should work.

Comment: I would like to set a resize the image to the size of Rectangle "r" and display this zoomed area in my dest-picturebox.

Comment: Than [Graphics.ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y8996ay8(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you search for.

Comment: I changed the code and put in "Draw.ScaleTransform(2, 2);" But the size remains the same! Is the sizemode of the dest-picturebox a problem or what else it could be? Thanks

Comment: Yes, die destination PictureBox must be configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

In each case, you have to handle the [PictureBox.SizeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx)-Property. It determines what the PictureBox does to the image when painting.

If you want to apply a customized Zoom-factor, you can use the [Graphics.ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform(v=vs.110).aspx)-Property. It allows you to scale the complete graphics. The Scaling can be done on the image itself by creating a bitmap (which has a Graphics-object you can use) or by overriding the [PictureBox.OnPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.onpaint(v=vs.110).aspx)-Method, which requires you to create a class deriving from PictureBox. That's the most flexible attempt because you can control everything by yourself - if you like to.´

**EDIT:**
Sorry for not being clear enough, the way using the `Paint`-event does not work. You need to make your own `PictureBox`-class (derive from PictureBox) and override the `OnPaint`-method. Then you can call `ScaleTransform` on the `Graphics`-object the PictureBox uses. I got a tested sample for you:

```
public class PictureBoxScaleable : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.ScaleTransform(.2f, .2f);
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even I set PictureBox.SizeMode = zoom, there is no resize (zoom) of the dest-image. As you can see I used the Graphics.ScaleTransform in the OnPaint-Method without success. Could you please explain me what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked (behind the SizeMode-Property)?

Comment: I tried it out, it works. I think you still use your Paint-event-handler. You must - as I stated not 100% clear in my answer - make a custom PictureBox (derive from PictureBox) and override the `OnPaint`-method. Please see my edit, that should definitely make you happy.